# Does the vscode extension package.json have an official schema?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there an official package.json schema for VS-Code extensions? I looked at the extension API documentation and they point you to NPMs package scheme, but it doesn't have all the same fields as described in the documentation. For example, `extensionDependencies` is defined in the documentation, but not NPMs package scheme.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json

Comment: somewhere internal to VSC, and thus in the repo, when you type in `package.json` you get suggestions of properties and default values.

Comment: I understand that. Ive done this, but there doesn't appear to be an actual JSON schema file.

Comment: it is small modification/addition to the Node package.json schema

Comment: I understand, but that also means that if I wanted to automate something, I would have to make manual edits to the schema every time they update it.

Comment: I guess the answer to this is no, there is not official schema. You need to modify Node package schema.

Comment: what kind of things do you want to automate

Comment: That shouldn't really matter because I just want to know if the json schema exists for vscode extensions. I am working on a package that allows you to develop an extension in a language other than typescript/javascript. I am programatically generating the package.json, and I want to generate classes from the schema that validate user inputs. I would like to be able to have this mechanism be derived straight from a json schema, that way if the schema is updated then the code automatically adjusts to the change.